# SilverStripe / Entwine hooking action to save-button

Tags: javascript, silverstripe

I'm trying to set an entwine hook to the save button inside a GridField edit form so that right before saving, a JavaScript function is executed.

I've tried the code below without success

```
$('button[type="submit"]').entwine({
    onclick: myFunction
});
```

What is the JavaScript code to hook an entwine onclick event on the GridField save button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bit of JavaScript will be called on press of the `GridField` save button.

```
(function($) {
    $.entwine('ss', function($){
        $('#Form_ItemEditForm_action_doSave').entwine({
            onclick: function(e) {
                console.log('Hello there');
                this._super(e);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

In SilverStripe 3.5 the default ID for the `GridField` save button is `Form_ItemEditForm_action_doSave`. If using the `BetterButtons` module the save button ID is `Form_ItemEditForm_action_save`.